# Is it possible to interrupt Javascript the flow of code with an Exception in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, exception

In Java, I would be able to do something like this, and I'm wondering if anything like this is possible in NodeJS?

```
function is_document_redundant(document) {
    // pseudo code, not real
    result = mongoose.Model.find(document.id);
    if (result != null) {
        throw new RedundantDocumentException(document);
    }
}

function save_document(document) {
    // pseudo code, not real
    try {
        is_document_redundant(document);
        mongoose.Model.save(document);
    } catch(err) {    
        console.log(err)
    }    
}
```

To be clear, if this line throws an exception:

```
        is_document_redundant(document);
```

Then this line should never happen:

```
        mongoose.Model.save(document);
```

That is, the script basically ends once the Exception is thrown.

I tried writing this code, but sadly, the script seems to continue past the Exception. Even when the code is redundant, and this throws an exception:

```
        is_document_redundant(document);
```

The script still executes this line:

```
        mongoose.Model.save(document);
```

I've got redundant documents piling up in the database. I'm wondering how I can avoid this, without having to have a bunch of ugly catch() blocks everywhere. I'd rather have the exceptions bubble up to the top and handle them all in the one catch block, but I need those Exceptions to interrupt the code and take the flow of control directly to that top level catch() statement.

Edit:

Okay, now I'm trying to use `await` but:

I've an Express route that starts like this:

```
app.post('/ams', async (req, res) => {

    try {
```

and then tried:

```
            let is_redundant = await document_is_redundant(AMS_945, unique_id);
            console.log(is_redundant);

    if (is_redundant) {
                throw new DocumentIsRedundantException(unique_id);
            }
```

but I get:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: `find` is async, you have to `await`. See the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findById) for some examples.

Comment: Your pseudo code should work - `throw`, `try`, `catch` are things that JavaScript inherited from Java. Please show your actual code, the one that doesn't work.

Comment: You say I shouldn't write pseudo code, but how could I write real code if I don't know how to translate a concept from Java into Javascript? The point is, I don't know how to write this in Javascript, so I'm resorting to pseudo code to imitate Java in Javascript. What actual code could I show you?

Comment: Yes, I am learning Javascript by asking questions on StackOverflow. That's the entire point of the website, yes?

Comment: Maxwell Yu offered a good answer.

Comment: This is why StackOverflow developed a reputation for being hostile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function is_document_redundant(document) {
    // pseudo code, not real
    result = await mongoose.Model.find(document.id);
    return result != null
}

async function save_document(document) {
    // pseudo code, not real
      cosnt isRedundant = await is_document_redundant(document)
      if (isRedundant) {
        mongoose.Model.save(document);
        return res.send('success')
      } else {
        return res.status(404).('refused to save')
      }
}
```

If you just want different results, you don't necessarily need to rely on error.

In client-side, you can use `res.ok` to check if the response you received is not 200 status code. (try-catch in client-side does not work since handmake errors are not network errors)

Comment: Your answer looks correct, but if I define an Express route as `app.post('/ams', async function (req, res) {` I still get "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" even though I put "async" in front of the function for the route.

Comment: I suspect I will be unpopular for mentioning this, but I thought the OP was asking about error handling with `try/catch` and `throw` and flow using those, yet that isn't covered here. In fact, it doesn't handle errors in either `await is_document_redundant(document)` or in `mongoose.Model.save(document);` so it's not a finished way to write this code.  Perhaps you can improve it to include full error handling?